# Can we customize the height of navigation bar?

Tags: android, uinavigationbar

Is it possible to change the height of the navigation bar only in my application.
[image: navbar]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, unfortunately you don't have control over system navigation bar height. There's a reason for that: some devices don't have it, while some devices give user control of how it looks (3 buttons vs gesture navigation). What you can do is hide/show it, or display your content behind it. Please refer to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation) for more details